# appending local domain to commonName and SubjectAltName when signing a CSR as my own CA

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, certificate-signing-request

I have a device that can generate its own keypair and a self-signed certificate based on those keys.
It can then generate a CSR from that and I can export that from the device. I cannot influence the contents of the cert or the csr.

The "CommonName" it uses is based on the DeviceName which cannot contain any '.'

Now when I sign that CSR with my local/private CA, and import the final cert back into the device and then goto https://mydevice.local the browser will of course complain because the "CommonName" for the cert is "mydevice" without the local domain suffix.

Is there a config option for the openssl command so that the "CommonName" gets a pre-configured suffix like ".local" in this example?
Also I would like to add the same String to "SubjectAltName" so that Chrome stops complaining as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CA software is free to throw away the subject and substitute its own. Everything in the CSR, except for the public key itself, is for informative purposes only.

For *openssl req* and *openssl ca*, use the `-subj` option to override the subject:

```
openssl ca -in device.csr -out device.crt -subj "/O=TabascoNet/OU=Devices/CN=mydevice.local"
```

To override the extensions use the `-extensions` option, and put the desired extensions (subjectAltName, extendedKeyUsage, etc) in openssl.cnf.

Comment: addendum: I finally used the "SubjectAltName" section to provide the IP address instead and do not rely on the CommonName to be correct since the device is a bit strange about importing signed certificates where the commonname has been altered by the signing CA...

Comment: You could provide the domain name in subjectAltName as well. The sAN extension causes clients to ignore the subject CN anyway.